# Kotlin Extension Any?.toString()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have been trying to use extension functions in Kotlin.

```
class ExtensionExample() {

   var name: String? = null

   fun Any?.toString() : String {

       if (this == null) {
           return "Value is null"
       }

       return "Value is not null"
   }
}
```

When I print the name variable like below

```
println(ExtensionExample().name.toString())
```

It should print like

```
Value is null
```

But it doesn't print like I expected. It only prints `null`.

Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) have [scopes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#scope-of-extensions). This is why it is not accessible outside of the `ExtensionExample` class.

Usually, extension functions are defined as top-level functions. That is, they tend to belong *outside of a class*.

Your `toString` extension is defined within `ExtensionExample`. [This is possible](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members), but it means **it is only available in the scope of this class, and this class only**.

Your `main` method is likely a top-level function (and not a member of that class), so it doesn't have access to this extension function.

Only other members can access this extension function:

```
class ExtensionExample {

    var name: String? = null

    fun Any?.toString(): String {
        return if (this == null) "Value is null" else "Value is not null"
    }

    fun foo() {
        println(name.toString())
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ExtensionExample().foo()
}
```

prints `"Value is null"`

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/jqQBh0)

The reason why it compiles is that the `toString` method that is being called is the [`Any?.toString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html) method from the [kotlin-stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html). That is, *this method already exists*.

> `fun Any?.toString(): String`
>
> Returns a string representation of the object. Can be called with a null receiver, in which case it returns the string "null".

**Move your extension function out of the class**. Your extension function will then *hide* the stdlib's extension, and any invocation in the same package not explicitly importing `kotlin.toString` will use your function.

**Here is a working version of your code**:

```
class ExtensionExample {

    var name: String? = null

}

fun Any?.toString(): String {
    return if (this == null) "Value is null" else "Value is not null"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(ExtensionExample().name.toString())
}
```

prints `"Value is null"`, as you wanted.

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/AiJbG8)

---

Note that you cannot hide a member function using an extension function. That is,

```
class Test {

    fun a() {
        println("a")
    }

}

fun Test.a() {
    println("b")
}

...
Test().a()
```

will result in "a" being printed.

The only reason why your `Any?.toString` works (after being moved out of the class) is that **`Any?` has no members** as it is not a class, but a nullable type with the class `Any`. The already existing `toString` method is also an extension, so yours is not hidden by any members.

Comment: Moved my extension function out of the class. Still no luck.

Comment: @ZumryMohamed Are you sure? My first code snippet works for me, and it prints "Value is null". [Here's an ideone link](https://ideone.com/AiJbG8).

Comment: Great answer anyway. Even though your first answer was failed, second edit has given me good understanding. I love your explanation. I will buzz you for my other questions too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Defining an extension function inside a class:**

If you want to leave the definition of `toString()` within `ExtensionExample`, you can **only** use it from there:

```
class ExtensionExample() {
    var name: String? = null

    // uses the toString() extension function defined in ExtensionExample
    fun useToString() = name.toString()

    fun Any?.toString(): String {

        if (this == null) {
            return "inside: Value is null"
        }
        return "inside: Value is not null"
    }
}
```

This

```
// uses the version of toString() defined in the Kotlin Standard library
println(ExtensionExample().name.toString()) 

// uses the inside version of toString()
println(ExtensionExample().useToString())
```

will print

> null
>   inside: Value is null

**Defining an extension function outside a class:**

But if you want to use it outside, you have to move it outside:

```
class ExtensionExample() {
    var name: String? = null

    // uses the toString() extension function defined in ExtensionExample
    fun useToString() = name.toString()

    fun Any?.toString(): String {

        if (this == null) {
            return "inside: Value is null"
        }
        return "inside: Value is not null"
    }
}

fun Any?.toString(): String {

    if (this == null) {
        return "outside: Value is null"
    }
    return "outside: Value is not null"
}
```

This

```
// uses the outside version of toString() which overrides the one from the Kotlin Standard library
println(ExtensionExample().name.toString())  

// uses the inside version of toString()
println(ExtensionExample().useToString())
```

will print:

> outside: Value is null
>   inside: Value is null

Answer (score 0):

> If a class has a member function, and an extension function is defined which has the same receiver type, the same name and is applicable to given arguments, the member always wins.

Your extension method can't shadow the built-in `toString` method on the `Any` (`Object`) class.

As for calling `toString` on a nullable type, this method is already in the Kotlin runtime:

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of the object. Can be called with a null receiver, in which case
 * it returns the string "null".
 */
public fun Any?.toString(): String
```

See also the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically) about the resolution of extensions.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the extension function isn't shadowing `Any.toString` (nor is it in scope at all).

Comment: Hmm. That is correct. Not only can it not shadow it, it's also not in scope. Thanks for the correction!